# How can I get rid of the one time stutter in CS:GO?

Tags: technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive

When playing CS GO, I always have sound stutter combined with heavy FPS lag / short freezes after a while. The funny thing is, it only occurs once per match and mostly at round start. However, this is annoying and can lead to a quick death if any enemy is around. I have verified the integrity of my game files, I have made sure my drivers are up to date, but nothing seems to fix this.

System:

- Win7 64bit
- AMD FX4300BE
- AMD HD7850
- 4GB Kingston RAM 1600 MHZ
- 512GB WD Green
- M5A78LM-USB3 Mainboard

I also would like to note that I changed Mainboard and CPU 2 months ago and this was happening on my old build with the AMD 965 as well. My old sound chip was a Realtek while this one is actually a VIA sound chip. So I think it might be something else.
Changing the games graphics options didn't do anything.

Comment: I am not sure but I had kinda the same. My problem was that the game needs to reload (also from the virtual ram) game files from the hard drive. I fixed it as I set the virtual ram on 0. The problem is that you only have 4GB of ram. That could lead to app crashes if you open several programs... But you could try it and see what happens.

Comment: from the comments of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5m5noTb0Pk it seems that problems could be: your vid card is in x1 PCI-e slot(and they say it should be in at least x4 PCI-e); multiple core rendering might be the problem as well. If it helps, I can post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Gerret You should never, ever set the virtual RAM of Windows to 0. Very bad things might happen. Even not if you have 32GB of RAM.

Comment: @Novarg Nope, my Video Card is in the 16x PCI-e Slot. There is only 1 for GPU and it is not my first PC I have built :).

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness ok I am not really into that thing... Bad section to discuss this but could u say me what could happen I am intressted into it. I have it now a month on 0 and nothing was happend yet. The only thing I know is that programms could crash if the ram is full

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5426041/understanding-the-windows-pagefile-and-why-you-shouldnt-disable-it In a nutshell: if your system runs out of memory, it goes down. Hard. it also works as file buffer and other operations Windows has to conduct. Not even Linux is really able to work without a swap file (which is the technical term for "Virtual Memory").

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness okay thank you for the information :). But I was really happy since csgo isnt freezing all the time cauze it has to reload from the vram ._.

Answer (score 1):

Stutter once per game (and mainly at the start) is highly likely to be the game still loading certain assets. You can try run around the entire map during warm-up round, it may help.

As for hardware, the best thing you can do to fix this issue would be to get a Solid State Drive and install your CS:GO onto there. This will mean that even if the game tries to load assets during the first few rounds, it will load them so fast the game should not stutter.

Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when a player joins the game? If so, I've also been experiencing this problem for a very long time but I think I may have found the solution. Try putting -nod3d9ex on CSGO's launch options. This completely removed the choppy fps when I first start the game up(which only happens if you have -novid on the launch options, to remove the intro clip when starting up the game) and I still need some more testing but I think it might have also solved the micro-stutters when someone joins the game

Answer (score -2):

Could this possibly be your issue?

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1983470/fps-lag-sound-stutter.html

This person managed to fix their problem by doing a clean install, and reinstalling all of his display drivers.

Comment: Please summarize the information contained at the link here.  That way, if that page ever goes down, your answer is still good.  Besides, it saves people a click.

Comment: No, it is not. It is not constant. It is just a few seconds in every match and only one time. I did a thorough Google search about this issue prior to posting here and tried a lot of things, so there is little chance you will find a solution with a simple Google search.

Comment: You mention that you have been having this problem with your old hardware as well. Which hardware did you keep to this build?